# code for saving png from canvas is not functioning properly

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am saving everything that was drawn on canvas. It saves the first drawing perfectly from canvas, but it keep's on saving the very first object that I saved from canvas. Here is my code for saving png from canvas.

```
View content = paint.canvas;
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream ostream;
try {
    ostream = new FileOutputStream(save_file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();
    Toast_Display.short_message(getActivity(), "File saved Successfully");
    dialog_save_file.dismiss();
    MainScreen.mFiles.setListView();
} catch (Exception e) {
    dialog_save_file.dismiss();
    Toast_Display.short_message(getActivity(), "An err0r occured while saving this file");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled the drawing cache via `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` and then you haven't cleared it.

You need to perform `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)` after performing `getDrawingCache()`.